# Ballistic Pendulum question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy

I am answering a question regarding the ballistic pendulum, and the teacher gave this worksheet. I have figured out both t (time) and the change in y. Where I am getting confused is where he wrote out $${PE = total\_\ *g*y}$$ what is "$total\_$"?? "$Total\_$" of what?!?!

Please help me as I am going out of my mind trying to understand what that is supposed to mean!

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I am guessing it is the total mass? Because mass is what should be in that place of the PE equation.

Comment: You were right, thanks! I went back and listened to the video and he very quickly and quietly said "total.... of m"

Answer (score 0):

If you look a little bit lower where he sets KE = PE, you will see that $$\text{total_} = (m+M)$$